# Why is a documentation proposal with 5 committers still in staging area?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

I proposed documentation for [esp8266](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/esp8266).

This proposal was accepted by 5 committers a couple of days ago, but the tag is still not available.

[image]

What is missing to start documentation on this tag?

Comment: @JarrodDixon It’s not fixed yet.

Comment: @JF you're correct - the bug I fixed was the underlying issue, but I didn't complete the DocTag's creation.  Pushing out a script now that will allow those completed proposals to be created. (Note that if anyone else had committed, the creation would have gone through).