# Error: Trying to commit to Telegram Documentation Proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

1. I saw I can join the [Telegram Documentation Proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/telegram/commit).
2. I clicked the big button commit, and this happened:

[image: commit bug stackoverflow]

3. I went back to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/telegram/commit
4. **Clicked Commit again**
5. The button changed to `You committed to this proposal 35 secs ago`

**Relevant info:**

- There were 4/5 Commiters. I was the 5th.
- Error redirect: https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/telegram/commit/submit
- Firefox 50 for Windows 10.
- I meet the requiremets for committing with 358 reputation and [3 answers in the tag with positive scores](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3494152%20%5Btelegram%5D%20is%3Aa%20score%3A1..).

Comment: The problem is that a cat operates the server, but all jokes aside have you tried clearing your browser cookie (or use a different browser, so a new one gets created)? Usually when stuff like this happens (not just on SO) its related to them. I'd find it a first diagnostic step to take.

Comment: You are not the first to report a problem being the last one to commit to a docs topic.  Well, you actually documented what went wrong.  Non-trivial dbase stuff, it is beta quality.  They are "workin on ur problemz".

Comment: @Xorifelse yes, SE has cats running their servers, unlike most sites, which have servers running on hamsters. SE is a popular enough site to actually need cats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a recent bug, stemming from code deployed a few days ago.

There was a null reference exception occurring when trying to create a new documentation tag (aka DocTag).  Because you are the last committer, you were seeing the exception.

The null ref was in our topic history code (i.e. where revisions are stored), which incorrectly assumed that a user would be attached to any topic draft passed into it.  When we do the initial DocTag creation, we don't create any drafts, and the code blew up when trying to determine the revision's owner.

The fix was simple, and a new unit test was created to (hopefully) prevent a regression.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: thanks for your answer Jarrod! Perfectly explained, is awesome to see stackoverflow developers hanging around here!

Comment: Is this related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338140/5244995 somehow?

Comment: @JF yes, that issue should also be fixed. Thank you.